# Releasing iPad app, after iPhone App is in the store

Tags: iphone

I have developed an iPhone app and preparing to upload it to iTunes store.Later on I want the iPad version of the app as well which I am currently working on.

So I would like to know whether it is possible to release the iPad app later as an update to the existing app in the store?

Answer (score 2):

So long as the iPad version is part of a universal bundle (iPhone and iPad resources in the same app) it would be treated as an update.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can. However, I think that you may be able to update it to a Universal application.

Most people just make the iPad version separate and call it App HD or provide universal versions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can make it Universal with an update, but you **can't stop support** a device after you published a universal app!

If you want to upload a different iPad-Version (e.g. AppXY HD) you can also create this in the same Xcode project and upload them as different versions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please clarify bit on "can't stop support"?

Comment: If you added universal support (iPhone and iPad-App in One) you can't say "Oh, I don't want to support iPad anymore" if you decide to support iPad AND iPhone you need to support it forever, or to remove it from the App Store

Comment: thanks for the comments. Our app got approved after releasing the second version with iPad as update.